# How to use multi table join query efficiently in SQL?

Tags: sql, hbase, apache-phoenix

I have Problem statement in Apache Phoenix in which I need to combine three tables for the result.
I have three views over Hbase table, Schema is as follow

Table group:-

### pk | Title | ownerId | data

Table Members:-

### pk | parentId | Email | data

Table userinfo:-

### pk | Email | First Name | Last Name

Now, I want to fetch groups whose title matches with input string if not matched then want to fetch groups whose members have a name that matches with the input string.

I already tried query as follow:-

```
select * from Group where pk like 'Prefix_%' 
and (TITLE like '%A%'
 or (OWNER_ID in
   (
      select parentId from MEMBERS where EMAIL in
      ( select distinct(EMAIL) from  USER_INFO
        where pk like 'PREFIX%' and 
        ( FIRST_NAME like '%A%' or LAST_NAME like '%A%')
      )
   )
) ) order by TITLE limit 5;
```

But, it's taking too much time also tried Left Join Query with similar but not give expected result.
Please Suggest how can I improve this?

Comment: do you have the indexes on required columns?

Comment: Despite all this information, I still don't actually see a clear problem statement.  What is this query supposed to be doing?

Comment: @sidgate No, they are views over the HBase, and we can't create an index over any column except row key.

Comment: A few questions : Is pk the rowkey in all tables ? And how much data is there in each tables? what is the expected query response time and what is the response time you are getting now?

Comment: @vmaroli yes, pk is the rowkey, its primary key. Around 1million data is there in each table, I am getting a response in 15sec expected is around 500ms

Comment: If pk is primary key query "select parentId from MEMBERS where EMAIL in" will result in reading the whole table. HBase query performance is best when you access the table using rowkey in "Where" clause.

Comment: @vmaroli yes you are right, Middle query is taking too much time due to a whole table scan. But I am not getting any alternative of it. Is Secondary index solve this?Or anything alse i can do?

Comment: @YashwantJoshi try using this code      select * from Group A 
INNER JOIN MEMBERS B ON A.OWNER_ID = B.parentId 
INNER JOIN USER_INFO C ON B.EMAIL = C.EMAIL
where A.pk like 'Prefix_%' and (A.TITLE like '%inputString%' or C.pk like 'PREFIX%' and (C.FIRST_NAME like '%inputString%' or C.LAST_NAME like '%inputString%'));